# lockbox (a boost-like container)

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

So I introduced myself to templates in C++11 and I have to say it's really confusing, but also very fascinating.  I just need to get my head around what happens at compile time so that I don't wind up making one line of driver code amount to a megabyte of asm...

Anyway, to teach myself I wrote a little container class.  It's a container that locks and unlocks a mutex on each read/write operation on a group of data.  There's still a few features I want to add to it, but that will take a lot of forced templating beyond compile-time recursion (more on this at the end).

Here is the code (updated 11/5):

```
#include <mutex>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstring>
#include "pack_size.hpp"
#include "pack_size_index.hpp"
#include "pod_test.hpp"

template <typename... item_t> class lockbox {
    static_assert(sizeof...(item_t) > 0, "empty lockboxes are not permitted.");
private:
    pod_test<item_t...> _test; //No data, tests to make sure item_t parameters are pod-only
    public: char _items[pack_size<item_t...>::value];
    std::mutex _mutex;

    template <size_t index, typename type_t, typename... args>
    static inline const void set_all(char* dest, const type_t& value, const args&... values) {
        type_t* align = (type_t*)&dest[pack_size_index<index, item_t...>::value];

        *align = value;

        set_all <index + 1, args...> (dest, values...);
    }

    template <size_t index, typename type_t>
    static inline const void set_all(char* dest, const type_t& value) {
        type_t* align = (type_t*)&dest[pack_size_index<index, item_t...>::value];

        *align = value;
    }

    template <size_t index, typename type_t, typename... args>
    static inline const void get_all(char* src, type_t& value, args&... values) {
        type_t* align = (type_t*)&src[pack_size_index<index, item_t...>::value];

        value = *align;

        get_all <index + 1, args...> (src, values...);
    }

    template <size_t index, typename type_t>
    static inline const void get_all(char* src, type_t& value) {
        type_t* align = (type_t*)&src[pack_size_index<index, item_t...>::value];

        value = *align;
    }

    template <size_t index, size_t... indices>
    static inline const void set_indices(char* dest,
                                         typename std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<item_t...> >::type& value,
                                         typename std::tuple_element<indices, std::tuple<item_t...> >::type&... values) {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<item_t...> >::type type_t;

        type_t* align = (type_t*)&dest[pack_size_index<index, item_t...>::value];

        *align = value;

        set_indices <indices...> (dest, values...);
    }

    template <size_t index>
    static inline const void set_indices(char* dest,
                                         typename std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<item_t...> >::type& value) {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<item_t...> >::type type_t;

        type_t* align = (type_t*)&dest[pack_size_index<index, item_t...>::value];

        *align = value;
    }

    template <size_t index, size_t... indices>
    static inline const void get_indices(char* src,
                                         typename std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<item_t...> >::type& value,
                                         typename std::tuple_element<indices, std::tuple<item_t...> >::type&... values) {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<item_t...> >::type type_t;

        type_t* align = (type_t*)&src[pack_size_index<index, item_t...>::value];

        value = *align;

        get_indices <indices...> (src, values...);
    }

    template <size_t index>
    static inline const void get_indices(char* src,
                                         typename std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<item_t...> >::type& value) {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<item_t...> >::type type_t;

        type_t* align = (type_t*)&src[pack_size_index<index, item_t...>::value];

        value = *align;
    }

public:
    lockbox(void) {
        _mutex.lock();

        memset(_items, 0, pack_size<item_t...>::value);

        _mutex.unlock();
    }

    inline lockbox(const lockbox<item_t...>& other) {
        operator=(other);
    }

    lockbox(item_t... items) {
        _mutex.lock();

        set_all <0, item_t...> (_items, items...);

        _mutex.unlock();
    }

    ~lockbox(void) {}

    lockbox<item_t...>& operator= (lockbox<item_t...>& rhs) {
        char buffer[pack_size<item_t...>::value];

        rhs._mutex.lock();

        memcpy(buffer, rhs._items, pack_size<item_t...>::value);

        rhs._mutex.unlock();

        _mutex.lock();

        memcpy(_items, buffer, pack_size<item_t...>::value);

        _mutex.unlock();

        return *this;
    }

    lockbox<item_t...>& set(item_t... items) {
        _mutex.lock();

        set_all <0, item_t...> (_items, items...);

        _mutex.unlock();

        return *this;
    }

    template <size_t... indices>
    lockbox<item_t...>& set(typename std::tuple_element<indices, std::tuple<item_t...> >::type... values) {
        _mutex.lock();

        set_indices <indices...> (_items, values...);

        _mutex.unlock();

        return *this;
    }

    inline lockbox<item_t...>& set(lockbox<item_t...>& other) {
        return operator=(other);
    }

    lockbox<item_t...>& get(item_t&... ref_items) {
        _mutex.lock();

        get_all <0, item_t...> (_items, ref_items...);

        _mutex.unlock();

        return *this;
    }

    template <size_t... indices>
    lockbox<item_t...>& get(typename std::tuple_element<indices, std::tuple<item_t...> >::type&... ref_values) {
        _mutex.lock();

        get_indices <indices...> (_items, ref_values...);

        _mutex.unlock();

        return *this;
    }

    inline lockbox<item_t...>& get(lockbox<item_t...>& other) {
        return other = *this;
    }

    static inline const size_t bytes(void) {
        return pack_size<item_t...>::value;
    }
};
```

pack_size:

```
template <typename... args> struct pack_size;

template <> struct pack_size <> {
    static const size_t value = 0;
};

template <typename type_t, typename... args> struct pack_size <type_t, args...> {
    static const size_t value = sizeof(type_t) + pack_size<args...>::value;
};
```

pack_size_index:

```
template <size_t index, typename... args> struct pack_size_index;

template <size_t index, typename type_t, typename... args> struct pack_size_index <index, type_t, args...> {
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) > 0, "index specified is out of bounds.");

    static constexpr size_t value = sizeof(type_t) + pack_size_index<index - 1, args...>::value;
};

template <typename type_t, typename... args> struct pack_size_index <0, type_t, args...> {
    static constexpr size_t value = 0;
};
```

pod_test:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... args> struct pod_test;

template <typename type_t, typename... args> struct pod_test<type_t, args...> {
    static_assert(std::is_pod<type_t>::value, "parameter pack contains non-pod types.");

    static pod_test<args...> node;
};

template <typename type_t> struct pod_test<type_t> {
    static_assert(std::is_pod<type_t>::value, "parameter pack contains non-pod types.");
};
```

Usage:

```
#include "lockbox.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    lockbox<float, double> box(3.5f, 6.7777899);

    float a;
    double b;

    lockbox.get<0, 1>(a, b) //get the items at indices 0 and 1 and
                            //store them in the variables specified

    std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl; //output: 3.5, 6.7777899

    lockbox.set<1> (5.67); //set the item at index 1 to the value specified

    lockbox.get(a, b) //get all items and store them in the variables
                      //specified (works the same with set as well)

    std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl; //output: 3.5, 5.67

    return 0;
}
```

What inefficiencies are present here?  I think set_all, get_all, set_indices, and get_indices might be creating an inordinate amount of functions, but that's all I can think of.  Is my format readable, naming conventions and spacing considered?

Answer (score 2):

I might be misreading things so correct me if I'm wrong but  Ithink your assignment operator can deadlock. A `lockbox` only makes sense when accessed from multiple threads, doesn't it (otherwise what would be the point)?

- Let's say we have two boxes `box1` and `box2` and two threads A and B.
- Both threads get a reference to both boxes.
- Each thread tries to copy the contents of one box into the other for some reason, so

  - Thread A executes: `box1 = box2` in order to assign the contents of `box2` to `box1`
  - Thread B executes: `box2 = box1` in order to assign the contents of `box1` to `box2`
- Now if the timing is right the following could happen:

  - Thread A executes the assignment operator and locks the right hand side first so `box2` is now locked.
  - Thread A gets interrupted or Thread B just manages to sneak in the next step on another CPU core
  - Thread B executes the assignment operator and locks the right hand side first so `box1` is now locked.
  - Thread B tries to lock the left hand side which is `box1` but that's already locked so it waits
  - Thread A picks up again and now tries to lock the left hand side which is `box2` but that's locked so it waits
  - Kaputt
- It's probably pretty rare but deadlocks often have the habit of being rare and non-determinsistic

**Update**: As mentioned by Loki in the comments you can use [`std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) to obtain multiple locks. It's employing a deadlock avoidance algorithm (I guess effectively something like: "try to lock all objects, if one failed, unlock all obtained locks and try again until you succeed").

Comment: Actually you are right, I'm not sure how to efficiently avoid that though.  Locking the this->_mutex and then rhs would do the same thing... I could make a copy of rhs._items in a local char array, but for large lockboxes this could be quite slow...

Comment: Scratch that, that's my only choice.  Code updated to reflect this change.

Comment: @NmdMystery: Could you not change the code you originally posted? Otherwise the provided answers will become useless. Either include the revised code further down in your question or ask a new question with your revised code for further comments.

Comment: @NmdMystery: This problem is solved by locking the resources in a specific order. If you use `std::lock()` and pass multiple objects it will always make sure that they are locked in a (unspecified but) specific order that avoids deadlock.

Comment: @ChrisWue Woops, I was thinking the opposite in that the post would be too long and nobody would want to read it.  The original code is lost now, though.

Comment: @LokiAstari Ah, didn't realize there was a static lock.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your internal storage field `char _items[pack_size<item_t...>::value];` may not be aligned properly, i.e. a `double` has an alignment of 8, but `lockbox<double>::_items` is only aligned by 4 (on 32-bit platforms).
2. Using `memset` and `memcpy` means your class only works for POD types and has undefined behaviour for non-POD types.
3. Since you're using C++11, why not just use `std::tuple`?

Comment: Actually I revised this to use tuple in a few places.  I wasn't aware of how tuple worked, I thought it was just sort of a container but it has all these extra meta-programming features I had no idea were there.  Will post an update in a moment.

Comment: I decided that only pod types should be used, since by design the lockbox makes it impossible to call methods of a non-pod anyway.  What should I do to fix the alignment problem, though?  I only own 64-bit machines so I can't go and test this on a 32-bit.

Comment: Also, testing sizeof(lockbox) gives me strange results - it seems to force an alignment of 8, is this just what sizeof does with non-pods or is this an issue I should be trying to fix?